# backbone.js - simple view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to run very simple view in backbone.js
Here is the code:

```
(function($){

    window.templateLoaderView = Backbone.View.extend({

        events: {
            'click #add_contact': 'loadTaskPopup'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            alert('templateLoaderView - initialize');
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        },


        render: function() {
            alert('templateLoaderView - render');
        },

        loadTaskPopup: function() {
            alert('templateLoaderView - loadTaskPopup');
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.templateLoaderView = new templateLoaderView();
});

<div id="add_contact">CLICK HERE</div>
```

When page loads, it alerts this `alert('templateLoaderView - initialize');`, but when I click the div, nothing happens.
Could you please tell what I do wrong?

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CPPsh/

Comment: No problem; it's always best to "show the code", but adding a fiddle demo on top of that makes it easier to help. I usually like to add one when it's appropriate and there's enough to go off of.

Comment: For a Backbone.js template tutorial, see: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are going wrong.

- When you create the view, it creates `this.el` as a DIV but it isn't rooted in anything
- Your event is trying to hook on the DIV of the view, which has no inner `#add_contact`
- You don't get an alert for `render` because nothing is ever calling `render`.

The most simple way to get your click handler to work is to tell the view which element to attach to:

```
window.templateLoaderView = new templateLoaderView({el: $("body") });
```

**Going further...**

Though, you may want your DIV to be created inside your view... it would go a little something like this:

```
(function($){

    window.templateLoaderView = Backbone.View.extend({

        template: _.template('<div id="add_contact">CLICK HERE</div>'),

        events: {
            'click #add_contact': 'loadTaskPopup'
        },

        render: function() {
            $(this.el).html(this.template());
            return this;
        },

        loadTaskPopup: function() {
            alert('templateLoaderView - loadTaskPopup');
        }
    });

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.templateLoaderView = new templateLoaderView();
    $("body").append(window.templateLoaderView.render().el);
});
```

Comment: I'm not real well-versed in Backbone; is this is a good demo? http://jsfiddle.net/CPPsh/1/ I adapted it from the jsfiddle linked here: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/

Comment: The line I'm not really sure of `_.bindAll(this, 'render');`. Not sure what that's supposed to do.

Comment: I was testing and realized that it cannot see anything outside my el. I did like this: `$('#add_contact').click(function() {
   window.templateLoaderView.loadTaskPopup();
  });`. It worked, but I would like to know if it is right way to do?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, that Fiddle definitely helped.  I used it to come up with both solutions.

Comment: Me too. I thought _.bindAll(this, 'render'); will trigger render function every time when any other function is called. Even after I was able to call `loadTaskPopup()`, I had to write `this.render();` inside `loadTaskPopup()` to run render.

Comment: @user616822 I have expanded your example to be a bit more idiomatically correct.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: @user616822 I think you misunderstand what `_.bindAll` does.  It does not trigger anything for you.  It binds the function to be the context of the object so that if `render` gets called as a callback, you can still reference `this` as the object, not the caller.  Since neither of these things are the case in your example, I removed `_.bindAll` in my solution.

Comment: Thank you, It is clear now :) Sorry for silly mistakes, I just start learning backbone :)